# Series: 1 + 1/3 + 1/5 +...upto N terms

Tags: c, loops, series

I was recently asked this question in a programming test. I can't seem to understand why I am getting the answer '1'. I am a beginner in the `C` programming language.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float c = 0;
    int n, i = 1;
    printf("Enter the number here: ");
    n = getchar();
    while (i <= 2*n - 1)
    {
        c = c + (1/i);
        i = i + 2;
    }
    printf("%f", c);
}
```

I have already tried using a `for` loop, but the answer remains the same. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `(1 / i)` takes place in integer arithmetic. You want 1.0 / i.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are doing integer division here: `c=c+(1/i);` For any value of `i` except `1` this will become `c+0`. Use `1.0/i` instead.

Comment: You may want to use `double` rather than `float`, it tends to have better range and precision.

Comment: Ok. I guess I need to revise data types first. BTW thanks for the suggestion, I changed every variable to float and I am getting the desired result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem in your code lies on this line:

```
c = c + (1/i);
```

Here, the operation performed inside the parentheses is ***integer*** division! So, when `i` has any value greater than `1`, the result will be zero. This zero is then converted to a float value.

To force the compiler to use ***floating point*** division, use this:

```
c = c + (1.0/i);
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Adrian's answer.

Another issue is because of the way floating point numbers are represented in a system when they are added in arbitrary order, precision can be lost.

To have maximum precision, floating point numbers should be added from smallest first to largest last.